# Webpack throws warning despite specifying mode

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

I am following a tutorial on webpack 4 where the person indicated that I do not need to specify a config file.

Here are my npm commands:

```
webpack --mode development
webpack --mode production
```

But yet i get the warning that no mode has been specified and thus production has been used my default.

May i know what is going on here?

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Datum_GUI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Frontend for the DATUM portal",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "GTI Storage SAN CIE",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.34.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `package.json` so that we can see the npm scripts?

Comment: @mgarcia i have edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is malformed, is missing an `=`, should be `webpack --mode=production` or `webpack --mode=development`